# Delete or get index number of a node in a NodeList based on an attribute value

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I have used querySelectorAll to get a NodeList from an XML document which, displayed through console.log, looks something like this:

```
0: <ThisNode AttributeName="a">​
1: <ThisNode AttributeName="b">​
2: <ThisNode AttributeName="c">​
```

Now I want to do something that disregards nodes/elements if they have an AttributeName value of "b". I can think of two ways I might do this:

Method 1: Delete nodes from the NodeList that have the AttributeName of "b".

Method 2: Get the index of the node with AttributeName "b" (which in this case would be 1), then do what I want by looping through all the index values other than that one.

However, I don't know how to do either.

Comment: I'd go with method 3: Combine an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with `:not()` ...

Comment: If you're using querySelectorAll to get the nodes, use a selector to exclude elements that attribute value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`not() pseudo-selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and get them with `ThisNode:not([AttributeName="b"]` or `[AttributeName]:not([AttributeName="b"]`

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('ThisNode:not([AttributeName="b"])');

//or
// const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[AttributeName]:not([AttributeName="b"])');

console.log(elements)
```

```html
<ThisNode AttributeName="a"></ThisNode>
<ThisNode AttributeName="b"></ThisNode>
<ThisNode AttributeName="c"></ThisNode>
```